# How to get QString from QListView selected item in Qt?

Tags: qt, qstring, qlistview

I need to get the selected item name in `QListView` as a `QString`. I have tried to google, but I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Look at the `QListView` documentation (especially its [member list](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview-members.html) ) to see how to get the current index (a `QModelIndex` object), and from the index, you'll be able to get its data content (a `QVariant` that you can convert to a `QString`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on selectionMode lets say you have `ExtendedSelection` which means you can select any number of items (including 0).

```cpp
ui->listView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
```

you should iterate through `ui->listView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes()` to find indexes of selected items, and then call `text()` method to get item texts:

```
QStringList list;
foreach(const QModelIndex &index, 
        ui->listView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
    list.append(model->itemFromIndex(index)->text());
qDebug() << list.join(",");
```

Comment: What is `model' here?

Comment: Is there a clean way to use that for QListViews with ```QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection``` disabled? I.e. if only one selection is possible and the loop and list therefore become needless?

Answer (score 19):

In case if `QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection` is disabled (only possible to select one item at a time), this is how you can do it without any loop:

```
QModelIndex index = ui->listView->currentIndex();
QString itemText = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
```